# Why is the alert not displayed in a new window

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a new window with some variable as follow:

```
var setScript = "<script>alert('test');<//script>";
var w = window.open();
var createBody = $(w.document.body);
var createHead = $(w.document.head);
createBody.html("");
createBody.html(p);
createHead.html(setStyle);
createHead.append(setScript);
```

I am not seeing the alert in the new window.

How can I resolve the issue.

`F12`:

[image]

Comment: Should `<//script>` be `<\/script>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check your error console?

Firebug give me this:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'


alert('test');<//script>
```

And like @j08691's comments you should change your first line code to this:

```
var setScript = "<script>alert('test');<\/script>";
```

Comment: How would I add the `DOCTYPE`? I think that needs to be added for the script to work correctly.

Comment: For this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459831/how-to-send-a-script-to-a-javascript-created-window

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you should do :

```
<script>
  (function(){
     var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
         head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
         script=document.createElement('script');

     //Do stuff with body

     script.onload = function() {
      alert("foo");
     };

     head.appendChild(script);
   })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/222/

use `document.write` on the new window

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open();
    myWindow.document.write("<script>alert('test');<\/script>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I actually wanted to use it for a different purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459831/how-to-send-a-script-to-a-javascript-created-window